# Use GSON with Fast Android Networking library

Tags: android, gson, android-networking

I'm using https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking in my project.

Does it support GSON?

if yes how does it work with it?
I tried searching it in the documentation but it only contains information about JacksonParserFactory.

I found a GsonParserFactory in it 
Using it like below

```
AndroidNetworking.setParserFactory(new GsonParserFactory());
```

but not sure how it works as I always get

```
org.json.JSONObject
```

Comment: FYI you always can convert a JSONObject or JSONArray to GSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GSON to parse the JSON response to your Java Class Object

```
private Gson gson;
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gson = gsonBuilder.create();

//If your response id JSON array
AndroidNetworking.get("your_url")
             .build()
             .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                  //For JSON array Response
                  List<YourModel> responseArray = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, YourModel[].class));  
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                // handle error
                }
            });

 //If your response is JSON object
 AndroidNetworking.post("your_url")
             .build()
             .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //For JSON object response
                  YourModel responseObject = gson.fromJson(response, YourModel.class);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                // handle error
                }
            });
```

Comment: how about .addJSONObjectBody on .post request ? when i passing data class there need JSONObject , i have convert by gson.toJson and casting to but the catch cannot be cast to